# New tags warning when trying to ask a question is not shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, error-message, popup

We have had two users ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359954/curiosity-cant-post-a-question-cross-browser) (10K only), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359991/not-being-allowed-to-post-question)) over the past 24 hours that tried to convince the meta crowd that there was an issue with posting their question. Both of them failed to define a clear enough description to make this reproducible or even diagnose.

However, both cases are probably caused by the new tag warning logic. The AJAX call to `/post/new-tags-warning` returns a warning and content but the popup with that content is never shown to the user in a specific case.

Step to reproduce (keep a developer console open)

1. Click ASK Question
2. Enter a good title
3. Enter a decent body
4. Enter a non existing tag but make sure the tag completion doesn't finish

   - don't type a space
5. Click the blue Post Your Question button
6. Nothing happens

   - the question isn't posted
   - no warnings or errors are shown
   - the network console shows a call to `/post/new-tags-warning` which returns`{"showWarning":true,"html":"<lots of html>"}`
   - you can repeat from step 5 leading to new calls to `/post/new-tags-warning` but no warning is ever shown.

Here is a screencast for those that are more visually oriented:

[image: fails posting]

The expected behavior is of course to show the warning that is returned from the server so the user knows why their question isn't posted.

I initially repro-ed this in Chrome/Win10 and I verified this behavior on Edge as well. I didn't bother with Firefox (but [@Machavity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359997/new-tags-warning-when-trying-to-ask-a-question-is-not-shown#comment536025_359997) did).

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: This is the difference between a bug report and a actionable bug report.

Comment: Just tried this on FF57 and reproduced exactly as outlined above

Comment: _Enter a decent body [...] `i++ + ++i`_: LOL!

Comment: I wonder how effective that warning is.  I suspect most would just click "Yes" - *Do whatever you want. Just post the question.*

Comment: Though you reproduced the bug in an excellent manner. But the actual person who posted the bug report got heavy downvoting, too bad he didn't had a proper in-sight on what was happening and what he was doing wrong!

Comment: @o_O voting on Meta can be harsh sometimes. You'll  need to bring your humor and your thick skin, lots of them.

Comment: @o_O The key to any bug report is reproduction. Just saying "It doesn't work for me!" isn't a good way to get it fixed. On Meta, it's likely to get you summarily downvoted

Comment: @o_O I recommend you to read [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359997/#comment536023_359997)

Comment: I'm not sure [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359991/4284627) has anything to do with this bug. The user who asked it doesn't have the privilege to create tags, and I tested it with a sock puppet who doesn't have the privilege to create tags and as expected I got the error message "Creating a new tag requires at least 1500 reputation" (see [here](https://i.imgur.com/PKCYKW8.gif)). I managed to reproduce the bug with my main account where I have enough reputation to create tags.

Comment: @DonaldDuck IIRC  seeing the tag selection popup is enough to cancel the error condition. Can you try simply pasting a full tag in, **NOT** triggering the tag selector and then click post question?

Comment: @rene I still got the error message with my sock puppet even when the tag selection popup didn't appear, as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/nXB8ICJ.gif). I also tried to do it with my main account after seeing the tag selection popup and nothing happened as you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/0D8pQd7.gif) (it's not really visible on the image, but I clicked on the Post Your Question button several times).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be fixed [along with the other errors that weren't showing up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360073/post-your-question-button-doesnt-work/360075#360075):

[image: new tag pop-up, correctly displayed]