# 'Post Your Question' button doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I am trying to post a question on Stack Overflow, but when I click on Post Your Question, nothing happens. I don't see any errors on the page and I've already closed my browser, logged out and back in and tried it in incognito mode.

[image]

[image: Screenshots]

Comment: Check your dev tools console. Do you see any errors there? I recall a recent question where this was an issue with Javascript not loading or something like that, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: You're hitting the throttle; also, you're apparently trying to post that question something like 5 times a second, which isn't gonna help with not getting throttled.

Comment: My dev tools are not open. Also WHAT! 5 times a second.  No way. Ive completely closed and reopened my browser and im not spamming the post button.

Comment: Not just you. something is fishy; lots of folks hitting the rate limiter are hitting it faster than should be humanly possible.

Comment: What do I need to cool it down? Does it still show Im spamming it? I havent hit the button in a while.

Comment: you're good; a dev has found the problem and will hopefully fix it soon.

Comment: @Kendra https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359991/not-being-allowed-to-post-question

Answer (score 31):

That's my bad. :/

I changed the submit element from `<input type="submit">` to `<button type="submit">` to support some UI changes we're making for Channels. What I didn't realize, however, was that even though it's a form post, we still have JavaScript hooked into content validation that's used to display errors, if any. I thought we always just rendered them on a page reload.

So, the selectors needed to be updated to look for `button[type=submit]` as well.

The fix is rolling out now.

Comment: Is [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359997/new-tags-warning-when-trying-to-ask-a-question-is-not-shown) the same root cause?

Comment: @rene Yeah, same thing.

Comment: Same problem on meta just now, I did an edit of html code in firefox debugger in order to post.

Comment: @pdem The button seems to work fine here. Can you elaborate on what happened? What sort of edit did you have to make?

Comment: In firefox, I did a right-click "modify element" (not sure for english translation) then in the html code I removed the "disabled" attribute on the button. Maybe there was a rule that I wasn't allowed to post at this time but I didn't see it displayed, and if it was the case, I have "broken the rule", see the post here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399836/should-i-edit-an-already-good-answer-or-make-my-answer-in-order-to-change-the-la?noredirect=1#comment785317_399836