# Review pages are missing syntax highlighting and - in close vote - duplicate tab doesn't open

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

Since today (maybe yesterday), the review screens appear to be broken. So far I have noticed the following issues:

- No syntax highlighting (close vote, reopen, maybe low-quality*)
- Duplicate tab(s) don't work (close vote, reopen)
- Clicking Edit in the Help and Improvement queue doesn't show any preview and also all the toolbar options are gone (like the Code Formatting button, Quote, Bold, Italics, etc.) (reported by [pushkin](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3479456/pushkin) in the comments, and I can reproduce) (help and improvement, suggested edits, reopen, first posts)
- Revision tab doesn't work (reopen)

I'm using Firefox 67.0b15 (64-bit) on Windows 10, but I also have it on Chrome 74.0.3729.131. I have hard refreshed the page a few times.

My console shows the error `TypeError: StackExchange.MarkdownEditor is undefined` at `full.en.js:4:24922`

---

<sup>*: I had already spent my low-quality time before I got annoyed by the lack of syntax highlighting in the close vote queue, and I cannot recall if it was the case or not for low-quality, but I assume it is the same underlying code.</sup>

Comment: I see at least one error in the console on `StackExchange.MarkdownEditor.creationCallbacks.add(n)` because MarkdowEditor is undefined.

Comment: Having the same problem with Firefox on macOS.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384455/what-happened-to-the-preview-and-the-tags-when-editing-a-post-in-the-suggested-e

Comment: @Jeremy but *adding them now will be too much effort* is a fine excuse in 2019 ...

Comment: @Jeremy yes. But the Tavern route is as effective for cases like this. Nobody is going to be killed or major loses to be expected from these bugs. Annoying? Sometimes. Can the team improve? Yes, they will, it might take 6 to 8 weeks, they'll get there.

Comment: @Jeremy yeah, they are dealing with legacy, but also [give them a bit of slack](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7700242#7700242). And aren't we all a logging engine, if we were [better at writing decent bug reports](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359997/new-tags-warning-when-trying-to-ask-a-question-is-not-shown) ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sorry about that. We rolled out a substantial refactoring of our JS (including converting some of it to Typescript), and evidently a few things got missed. We've rolled back the change in order to investigate and re-test.

Comment: Thanks, I did a quick check and things appear to be working again.

Comment: Hi Adam, this issue is still persisting for me and [some other users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384481/possible-bug-in-stack-overflow-editor-not-showing-any-functional-options-to-for)

Comment: @anky_91 looks like different bug.