# What happened to the preview and the tags when editing a post in the Suggested Edits Queue?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

When I go to "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" I see something like this:

> [image]

There is no preview (clicking "hide preview" removes a tiny bit of whitespace). Tags are not formatted, and trying to add another tag doesn't show the popup showing suggestions. The toolbar is missing. Also, saving the edit takes me back to the post (where I can see how I horribly mangled the post and rush to fix it) instead of to the next suggested edit.

This is probably related to [Review pages are missing syntax highlighting and - in close vote - duplicate tab doesn't open](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384453/6083675), since I'm also seeing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'creationCallbacks' of undefined

It's also definitely related to [No options while editing a post body](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327586/323179) where the user does not have edit privileges and is editing from a different queue.

This only happens on Stack Overflow, best I can tell. On the two other sites I checked (ELU and ELL) it worked correctly. It also works right when I make my own edits outside the queue.