# Possible bug in Stack Overflow: editor not showing any functional options to format question

Tags: bug, status-completed, editor

Please take a look at the picture below:

[image: All of the icons are missing from toolbar above the editor.]

I've tried clearing my browser's cache and history as well as restarting my browser, but the editor still doesn't show anything. I use Firefox. **The editor displayed the bold button, italic button etc. correctly on Meta Stack Overflow, though.**

**EDIT**

It's working correctly now.

Comment: This was [reported and fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384453/review-pages-are-missing-syntax-highlighting-and-in-close-vote-duplicate-tab) several hours ago. I guess they tried to roll out their TypeScript refactor again...

Comment: I still dont see it

Comment: @CodyGray this issue still persists unfortunately.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What browser are you using? Do you see any javascript errors in the dev console?

Comment: @AdamLear FYI I can't repro on FF win10 but my dev console is rather noisy with warnings about ReferenceErrors in full.en.js, tageditornew.js, jquery.min.js and wmd.en.js. But no errors. I recall I saw those warnings before so that is not something that was introduced recently. Maybe a sign, not a root cause.

Comment: @rene I don't even see any warnings in either Chrome or FF.

Comment: @AdamLear this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9HUd.png but on Chrome I have no warnings either.

Comment: Happened to me twice. All the buttons disappeared suddenly. I tried Chrome, Firefox and Opera but all had the same issue. After clearing everything cache, cookies, history the buttons appeared again.

Comment: It's working now for me.