# Could not submit question, because I wasn't able to format code. The toolbar disappears

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

I'm trying to submit my question, but I cannot format my code, because all the toolbars disappeared. As you can see in the picture, there's only the add picture button, and all other tools were not available.

[image]

Comment: This should be posted on [meta]. (Note that you can also format code using the keyboard with Ctrl+K. But this looks like a bug, especially if you can reproduce it.)

Comment: I tried Ctrl + K but then the code disappeared.

Comment: [This again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384453/review-pages-are-missing-syntax-highlighting-and-in-close-vote-duplicate-tab), maybe?

Comment: @Stijn that or simply some of the javascript needed is blocked for the OP.

Comment: If you can, please open the developer console of your browser (F12 will work if you're on Windows and using one of the major/mainstream browsers) and report here any errors found in the console and errors from the network tab. A reload might be needed to see those.

Comment: Can you add a border to the screenshot? That would make it clearer what is part of the screenshot and what is not.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, although the tools for formatting code are not available. I just need to put my code into the block of the triple ` and the question is allowed to submit.