# I have Found Bug in Edit Question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

**It allow me to edit anyone's Question from StackOverflow.**

When I see anyone's question, it allows me to edit that question, even if I have tried to edit someone's question and it is done.

Comment: Are you saying that instead of you "suggesting" an edit (which is perfectly valid), your changes took effect immediately? If so, can link to a post where this happened?

Comment: That is not a bug, it's by design. Also, [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23730359) has gone into a review queue and has not taken effect yet. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) explains how editing works here.

Comment: There you go, the suggested edit has been rejected as if you didn't make the edit at all. Now you should see the original post without your edits.

Comment: Learn more about editing here https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'm new to stackoverflow so it's my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to Meta! And thank you for taking the time to report a "bug".

Unfortunately

> It allow me to edit anyone's Question from StackOverflow.

is not a bug but a feature of this site. A moderator indicated this on your question by adding the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) to your bug report.

Any user, even anonymous visitors, can [suggest edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to any posts<sup>1</sup>. In that sense the content here is collaboratively improved.

The user interface does inform you that your edit is put in a [review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23730359) and it does keep your revision shown only to you so you're not assuming your edit didn't make it and would suggest it again.

While we sometimes find bugs in the software that powers the Stack Exchange network, we're not supposed to be testing in production (and *I posted gibberish to do some testing* is not an excuse when you get your account banned or suspended for being caught doing so) . When you see something awkward during your normal usage of the site, make sure you checked the Help center and Meta first to see if similar issues have been raised already. Only if it is clear the behavior is out-of-band do post a bug report.

On top of that bug reports need to be actionable. Here is an example of a well received bug report I posted [New tags warning when trying to ask a question is not shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359997/new-tags-warning-when-trying-to-ask-a-question-is-not-shown) so you have something to compare your report against.

<sup>1. except protected and locked posts</sup>